# Fetch all data of Users

Tags: users, meta-query

I am trying to fetch `users` All information by using below code.

```
if($_POST['orga_id']) {
        $users_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                        'value'   => $_POST['search'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'last_name',
                        'value'     => $_POST['search'],
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'organisation',
                    'value'     => $_POST['orga_id'],
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'available',
                    'value'     =>  1,
                    'compare'   => '=',
                ),          
            )
        ));
    } else {
        $users_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'first_name',
                        'value'   => $_POST['search'],
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'last_name',
                        'value'     => $_POST['search'],
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'key'       => 'available',
                    'value'     =>  1,
                    'compare'   => '=',
                ),          
            )
        ));
    }

    //$users_found = $users->get_results();

    $args = array(
        'fields' => 'all',
        'orderby'     => array( 'last_name' => 'asc', 'first_name' => 'asc' ),
        'meta_query' => $users_query,
    );

    $users2 = get_users($args);
```

But I am getting only few information like below.

```
ID: "548"
​​​​
display_name: "AaronKew"
​​​​
user_activation_key: ""
​​​​
user_email: "aaron.kew@nsw.scouts.com.au"
​​​​
user_login: "AaronKew"
​​​​
user_nicename: "aaronkew"
​​​​
user_pass: "$P$BauZua136ZxKPY9Nu2FpmZT1LRmOLr1"
​​​​
user_registered: "2022-02-06 03:17:50"
​​​​
user_status: "0"
​​​​
user_url: ""
```

[image]

I am not getting `first_name` and `last_name` of users.

Comment: this is a very strange and incorrect usage of `WP_User_Query`, what resources told you to do it this way?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. Actually I am new to `meta_query`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually since you already have the ID you could just loop through and get the meta.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

```
get_user_meta(ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's been a fundamental misunderstanding of how `meta_query` works. `meta_query` is meant to be an array, not a new `WP_User_Query`.

This is what you've done:

```php
get_users( [
    ...args
    'meta_query' => new WP_User_Query( [ ...meta args ] ) // incorrect usage!
] );
```

This is what you should do instead:

```php
$query = new WP_User_Query( [
    ... args,
    'meta_query' => [ .... meta args ]
] );
```

Remember, `get_users` is a wrapper around `WP_User_Query`, and `WP_User_Query` is for finding users, not specifying meta parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Tom J Nowell for your Answer. Actually  I am new to `meta_query`. I am learning `meta_query`. I am not clear. How can I use  `get_users()` to all information of users ? Thanks.

Comment: @Foysal did you read the answer? I'm unsure what was unclear. If you are looking for a copy paste solution then I cannot provide that on principle.